# Why I'm facing problems with @Href("path") and not with @Url.Content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I was writing a question asking why @Href isn't recognizing the path correctly.

E.g.

```
@helper CSS(string cssFile, string media = "screen") {
    <link href="@Href("~/content/stylesheets/" + @cssFile)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="@media" /> 
}
```

is throwing sereval js 404 error trying to found the resource in

- http:// localhost/content
- http:// localhost/dashboard/content

and never what I want:

- http:// localhost/MySite/content

So them I found the interesting part: `@Url.Content` instead of `@Href` works fine! **Why!?**

Therefore this is not the bigger problem, the issue is that in App_Code @Url doesn't exist in the context. What I can use then.

Comment: Where does MySite come from ?

Comment: The usual site is localhost/MySite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN is your friend. From [WebPageRenderingBase.Href](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagerenderingbase.href%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) Method:

> When overridden in a derived class, builds a URL using the specified
>   parameters.

Whereas from [UrlHelper.Content Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx):

> Converts a virtual (relative) path to an application absolute path.

The tilde in your path makes it a virtual path, which apparently @Href() doesn't understand.

Comment: Ok! You are right. This is a fail point in my question. In my App_Code I don't have the @Url, cause this is not web page. So how can I handle this?

Comment: You're probably better off passing the result of `@Url` to your code than trying to call it directly, since it needs the `HttpContext` (especially the `Request` and `RouteData`) in order to figure out the correct path.